# What is considered a 3d sound?

Tags: sound-design

There is a person who makes sounds. I'm curious if this type of sound is considered a 3d sound. What defines a sound as 3d?
When was the first 3d sound made in music? Has it always been around?

Comment: Are you asking about [3D sound effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_audio_effect), and if so, what is your particular question ?

Comment: There is _no such thing_ as 3D sound. Humans have two ears, allowing us to only perceive sound (brain) as a combination of two point-sources of monophonic data (ears). We perceive sound as "stereo" although it can be recorded and processed in many more ways than this - mono, coincident stereo, spaced (time-delay) stereo, multi-mic, ambisonic. 

The term "3D" sound is simply a marketing term.

If you are referring to "Virtual Reality" sound, research "Ambisonics".

Comment: @mark - Agreed, but: *There is no such thing as 3D sound*. Well, technically all sound is 3D, since it fills a volume of space (-:

Comment: @JimMack "filling a volume of space" isn't justification in any way for defining 'all sound as 3d'. With reference to a 3 dimensional space, all sound sources in that space have intensity, frequency, phase and position but are themselves can be derived from point-sources. There's really no point in giving credence to what is effectively a 'marketing' term simply to add to the confusion.

Comment: @Mark - Did your humor license expire? I guess you missed the part where I agreed with you.

Comment: I'm actually curious to know if sound that I make would be considered 3-d.  I'm allowed to post a link that will take you to a sound I made?

Comment: My idea of how I am understanding sound as a three D experience from the stand point of a listener is something like an effect of distance and levels of pitch and key being operational in their appearing to be coming from here and then there but then in and out from behind that sound over there when it seemed to be over here a second ago.  I do say appear in a correct way because that is my experience of the moment as I encounter the sound.

Comment: I am grateful for your responses thank you for your time and information and willingness to share with me.